# Require a minimum normal site rep (5, 10, ...) to ask questions on a meta site?

Tags: discussion, reputation, asking-questions

I think I may have found a solution to the stream of questions that belong on SO that arrive here: why don't we require a (low) minimal reputation on Stack Overflow to allow posting on meta?

I think this makes perfect sense since I wonder:

**How can someone contribute to the functioning (meta) of a site if he/she has absolutely no experience with the site in question?**

I think most of us discovered meta after being on SO for a while, anyway.

Of course, I'm well aware that the discussion of "should we require minimum rep for asking questions" has been made dozens of time for SO and other SE sites, and the answer is a big **no** to which I fully agree. But meta already works differently in so many ways. Surely this wouldn't even be the most dramatic difference?

This question also applies to other SE and Meta SE sites.

Comment: MSO is the network wide Meta. Not just for SO users.

Comment: @Bart, okay, but then we could require a minimum rep on **any** normal site? Then at least they know what a meta site is.

Comment: MSO is also the site for user support. If the users have trouble using any of the site functions, e.g. login problems, having a rep requirement would prevent them from getting proper help.

Comment: Given its function as the network wide Meta, I don't mind it being a bit of a catch all. As was discussed just last week (I think) the "problem" is manageable and doesn't really require any intervention at the moment.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester you mean like a [Participate in meta privilege](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/privileges/participate-in-meta)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter whose name is hereby very much justified: I forgot about that...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There already exists a limitation for participating in a sites meta area.

Ironically, I'll post a link to the [meta privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/participate-in-meta) :)
Here on the global meta site for all Stack Exchange sites, there is no such limitation.

I'm fairly sure that the limit is 5rep on all sites (but I haven't checked them all). I do know that reputation required for certain privileges varies across the network...

Comment: But not on Meta SO.

Comment: Thanks @bar - indeed the network wide meta is an exception...

Answer (score 2):

Going to note that the reason the limit is so low on other metas and zero on this one is it includes support.  If a user posts one question, gets a downvote and a closure and doesn't understand why, they should be able to *and are actively encouraged to* come to meta to clarify how to participate productively.  I've seen many rant-ish complaints wind up on here for that reason, but a few very constructive posts as well.

I personally did something similar on programmers.SE - at that point I had about 300 rep from a few good answers but my questions tended to be bad, so I posted basically saying, "okay, if this question is not constructive then I don't get how this site works."  But received some constructive help and can participate more effectively now.